# MYSQL updating DATETIME Data Type (h:i:s only)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

For example I have `(2013-06-03 22:00:00)` stored in a table called `Log`.

I want the updated output to be like (2013-06-03 07:30:00), modifying only hours, minutes, and seconds.

How can I update only the time?

*PHP version is 5.3*

Answer (score 1):

In mysql:

```
update your_table set your_field=concat(date(your_field),' 07:30:00');
```

Comment: Date function extract the date part of a date or datetime expression. Then you can concatenate the time part.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will try it shortly!

Comment: Really, if you prefear, you can do it with php:
$newTime=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($oldTime))." 07:30:00";